# JS: how to filter table using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I need to use for filtering table rows:

```
setFilterString("Filter");
```

But I have a problem. I can set it to

```
setFilterString("OrderID = 5");
```

and it will filter out row where OrderID is equal to 5 but if i try using a variable that has a value taken before like this

```
setFilterString("OrderID = vOrderID");
```

I get error "Invalid column name 'vOrderID'." (as vOrderID is variable and not a column, I guess)

I have seen somewhere in filter section inputting something like this `("OrderID = '" & vOrderID & "'")` but it doesn't have any result at all for me. Doesn't even throw any error in the console.

Comment: Very close use `+` for concatenation i.e.  `("OrderID = '" + vOrderID + "'")`

Comment: @Satpal Solved. as it is a comment, cant marked as a solving answer. Co you mind telling me where i could look for information on this kind of thing? what the + means here or why it is in such syntax exactly? I imagine I'm gonna need this in the future too

Comment: Always look in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: except im not sure what to look for exactly

Comment: [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript assumes you are just passing a string to the function. If you want to use the variable, you should try this:

```
setFilterString("OrderID = '" + vOrderID + "'"); // Results in OrderID = '5'
```

or

```
setFilterString("OrderID = " + vOrderID); // Results in OrderID = 5
```

depending on the body of your function.

Comment: first one means it puts 5 as a string and the second one as a number?

Comment: In this function it won't make any difference as you concatenate a string with a variable which results in a string. If you would use a separate parameter in your setFilterString function for the vOrderID variable, then it would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` instead of `&`: `setFilterString("OrderID = " + vOrderID)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use "+"  for merge strings:
`setFilterString("OrderID = " + vOrderID)`

You can also try to use ${idvOrderID} inside string:
`setFilterString("OrderID = ${vOrderID}")`

Or:
`setFilterString(sprintf("OrderID = %s", vOrderID))`

Remember about difference between ' and "

Comment: first one works, the latter two don't
Second ones throws an error:
`Parser error at line 0, character 10: Invalid input character "$".; ("OrderID = {FAILED HERE}${vOrderID}")`
Last one throws in console this:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: sprintf is not defined`